# TreeSet implementation?

Tags: sorting, binary-search-tree, treeset

I tried to implement a TreeSet instead of a ArrayList due to the fact that I need to sort that list. The original code was:

```
private final List<Report> reports = new ArrayList<Report>();
public void receiveReport(final Report report) {
        this.reports.add(report);
    }
```

To my version:

```
private final TreeSet<Report> reports = new TreeSet<>();
public void receiveReport(final Report report) {
        reports.add(report);
    }
```

and it show me just 1 report and this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class dsa.speedcamera.Report cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (dsa.speedcamera.Report is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; 
java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1563)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.addEntryToEmptyMap(TreeMap.java:768)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:777)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:534)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at dsa.speedcamera.ProvidedImplementation.receiveReport(ProvidedImplementation.java:19)
    at dsa.speedcamera.ProvidedImplementation.demonstration(ProvidedImplementation.java:73)
    at dsa.speedcamera.ProvidedImplementation.main(ProvidedImplementation.java:92)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the Report file:
package dsa.speedcamera;

```
public class Report {
    public TimeID timeID;
    public int speedLimit;
    public String carRegistration;
    public int speedRecorded;
    /** 
     * Returns a String representing the values in this object so that is can
     * be directly printed with System.out.println();
     */
    public String toString() {
        return timeID.toString() +  
        "\nSpeed limit: " + speedLimit + " mph" +
        "\nCar registration: " + carRegistration +
        "\nSpeed recorded: " + speedRecorded + " mph";
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: `Report` is a class, there must be some attributes in this class (Integer, String) on which sorting should be applicable. You need to provide that information to TreeSet, right?

Comment: @Sim Sam I edit it and now you can see the report class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For user-defined objects, you cannot directly add to TreeSet. You need to give TreeSet an attribute on which sorting should be applicable. For example, are you sorting based on `speedLimit` or `speedRecorded`? How do I know? How does TreeSet know?

To give TreeSet that information you need to provide what we call a custom Comparator.

Please go through the following articles, they'll help you.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-comparator-method-in-java/

https://www.callicoder.com/java-treeset/